# Mixed authentication in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, httpmodule, basic-authentication, mixed-authentication

I've got an ASP.NET application which uses forms authentication.

We're adding on an HttpModule that responds to requests in the /webdav folder and below.  We need to use basic/digest authentication for these requests.

With `<authentication>` set to Forms in the root web.config, requests from webdav clients are receiving a 302 redirecting the user back to the login page.

Is [MADAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479391.aspx) the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think MADAM would work well for you.

I'm using MADAM to make RSS feeds available that are specific to logged in users accessible to RSS Readers.  I am also planning on using it when we implement mobile app access into our application.  That way we can use the same controller logic and change the authentication using MADAM.

I would suggest that you use HTTPS requests if you're doing BASIC authentication.  Also, if you are using IIS 7, make sure you add the http modules configuration into the system.webServer/modules section.  I wasn't paying much attention and wasted time diagnosing why it was working locally and not on the development server in IIS 7.

Comment: Thanks - I'll give it a more detailed look.